# AWS CLI Error parsing parameter '--container-definitions': Invalid JSON: Invalid \e

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I'm trying to update a task though AWS CLI, but in the moment of register the task, i have a problem with the container definition i'm passing to it.

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --container-definitions "$task_def" --family $TASK_FAMILY | $JQ '.taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn'
```

`Error parsing parameter '--container-definitions': Invalid JSON: Invalid \escape: line 130 column 23 (char 3202`)

the problem in that line is an environment variable with a special character () a backslash

```
{
                        "name": "FTP_USER", 
                        "value": "xxx\xxxxx"
}
```

If i try to scape the character with double back slash \, it doesn´t response to me an error, but the environment variable is setup with double \ and the connection to the FTP of course doesn´t work.

```
{
                        "name": "FTP_USER", 
                        "value": "xxx\\xxxxx"
}
```

Someone can help me with this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Try specifying the JSON as a file and loading it from said file?

Comment: Yeap, that works, Thanks